# Object losing data when calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ()

Tags: c#, sql, database, serialization, deserialization

I'm pulling JSON from a database and trying to deserialize it back into an object. But explained below, it loses object properties after I deserialize.

**My code:**

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(PartsDatabase.connString)) {

                string query = @"SELECT [JSON] FROM parts WHERE [Id] = @id";

                using (SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {

                    sqlcommand.Connection = conn;

                    conn.Open();

                    sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

                    MessageBox.Show(sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                    Part p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Part>(sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(PartsDatabase.DisplayObjectInfo(p));

                    tb_PartNumber.Text = p.GetPartNumber();
                    cmb_revision.SelectedIndex = cmb_revision.FindString(p.GetRevision());
                    tb_partName.Text = p.GetPartName();
                    tb_workOrder.Text = p.GetWorkOrder();
                    tb_serialNo.Text = p.GetSerialNumber();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
```

**The Output from `MessageBox.Show(sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`**:

```
{"PartNumber":"20584","PartName":"FOO, BAR","Revision":"0","SerialNumber":"11111","WorkOrder":"22222"}
```

**The Output from my debug method `MessageBox.Show(PartsDatabase.DisplayObjectInfo(p));`**:

```
 System.String PartNumber = 
 System.String Revision = 0
 System.String PartName = FOO, BAR
 System.String WorkOrder = 22222
 System.String SerialNumber = 11111
```

**My `Part` class**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PartsDatabase {

    [Serializable]
    public class Part {

        [DataMember]
        public string PartNumber { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PartName { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Revision { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SerialNumber { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string WorkOrder { get; private set; }

        public string GetPartNumber() {
            return PartNumber;
        }
        public void SetPartNumber(string value) {
            PartNumber = value;
        }
        public string GetPartName() {
            return PartName;
        }
        public void SetPartName(string value) {
            PartName = value;
        }
        public string GetRevision() {
            return Revision;
        }
        public void SetRevision(string value) {
            Revision = value;
        }
        public string GetSerialNumber() {
            return SerialNumber;
        }
        public void SetSerialNumber(string value) {
            SerialNumber = value;
        }
        public string GetWorkOrder() {
            return WorkOrder;
        }
        public void SetWorkOrder(string value) {
            WorkOrder = value;
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public Part(string workOrder, string partNumber, string revision, string partName, string serialNumber) {

            WorkOrder = workOrder;
            PartNumber = partNumber;
            Revision = revision;
            PartName = partName;
            SerialNumber = serialNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

**My serialize method:**

```
public static string serialize(Part p) {

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
        }
```

You can see it loses the PartNumber after the deserialize method. Calling `Console.WriteLine(p.GetPartNumber());` will print out a blank line. What could be wrong? PartNumber is not the only property the object loses but I had to truncate it for this question. It loses some properties but not others. It's consistent though, meaning it's always the same properties that fail to deserialize. Thanks!

Comment: That's not the only thing that's different.  The workorder is a different number.  Seems as if your debug method is looking at a different record.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My mistake, I changed the json for privacy reasons but forgot to change the other output. It is pulling the correct record. I edited my post to reflect

Comment: The code and data you've posted looks fine to me.  If I put it into VS it's just going to no-repro.  Check your spelling and casing *everywhere.*

Comment: And make sure your constructor is getting passed the proper data correctly.